# Conditional rendering in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to render some part of the template if it is a certain page of the web site? Or is it also possible to include specific javascripts in application.html.erb layout if it is a certain page?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: nothing special because I do not know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) can help you.

For example:

layout.html.erb

```
...
<head>
  <%= yield :scripts %>
</head>
...
<%= yield %>
```

view.html.erb

```
...
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <script>..</script>
<% end %>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to what railscard said I usually do this:

In the layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag content_for?(:stylesheets) ? yield(:stylesheets) : "application", :debug => Rails.env.development? %>
```

Then inside a view

```
<% content_for :stylesheets %> my_view.js <% end %>
```

That way you only have to set content_for if there is something special you want to change the top level file loaded from sprockets.

Comment: You should have a helper that takes any number of arguments (*args), and do the content_for for you, so that you can just write: `<% stylesheets "styleshee1", "stylesheet2" %>` in your views.